# exec() doesn't seems to execute .exe

Tags: php, html, exe

First, I have a website in local with **Wamp64**. And I would like to execute **a .exe** file.

So I use the `exec()` function like this :

```
$output = exec("cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ENENSYS\DiviSuite' & DiviSuite-CLI.exe --in-rf --in-rf-standars T --in-rf-frequency=474 --in-rf-bandwidth=8 --in-rf-duration=20 --out-file C:\wamp64\capture.ts");
```

The program has to record a stream and put it in C:\wamp64\ but it doesn't whereas when I execute the same command line in the **MS DOS** console it works.

Also, when I do an echo of $output the echo display nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$output = exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ENENSYS\\DiviSuite DiviSuite-CLI.exe --in-rf --in-rf-standars T --in-rf-frequency=474 --in-rf-bandwidth=8 --in-rf-duration=20 --out-file C:\\wamp64\\capture.ts");
```

It should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to use `shell_exec` in this case because you are executing multiple commands.

doc: http://php.net/manual/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Can manually cd into DiviSuite folder and try to run that php file from DiviSuite folder , removing cd command from exec. ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(function(){
if(($olddir=getcwd())===false){
throw new RuntimeException('getcwd() failed!');
}
if(!chdir('C:/Program Files (x86)/ENENSYS/DiviSuite')){
throw new RuntimeException('failed to enter DiviSuite folder!');
}
$output=array();
$ret=0;
exec('DiviSuite-CLI.exe --in-rf --in-rf-standars T --in-rf-frequency=474 --in-rf-bandwidth=8 --in-rf-duration=20 --out-file C:\wamp64\capture.ts',$output,$ret);
if($ret!==0){
echo "WARNING, DID NOT RETURN 0. THIS IMPLY AN ERROR IN MOST PROGRAMS.".PHP_EOL;
}
var_dump('returned:',$ret,'output:',$output);
chdir($olddir);
})();
```